# Is my partition transform in Vega written correctly because the graph that is visualized is not accurate

Tags: graph, charts, partition, vega, hierarchical

I am creating a hierarchical representation of data in Vega. To do this I am using the stratify and partition transformations. The issue that is occurring lies with the x coordinates that are generated with the partition transformation. In the link, navigate to data viewer and select tree-map. The x0 and x1 for the initial id, the top most element, "completed stories" within the hierarchy ranges from 0 - 650. The next two elements, "testable" & "not testable", should have a combined x range of 0 - 650. But instead, they range from 0 - 455. The width should be based on their quantities, located in the "amount" field. Any suggestions as to why the rectangle that is generated is not commensurate with the quantities.

[Link to Vega Editor with code shown](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4Ig7glgJgLgFiAXANgKwAYA0I4FMIDmcMSAzBtlAIYxVIDaoAdlQLa5IgBOVYAcgFdWAI1xcAziGwA3KgBsBuSYkYhonAMYB7VgAc5uGLigACcTC1cISqSF1UuuJiURMBcudjZaBzsgA5kAE4AX0xQdUQQI3MqYQNbe0c-KO09AyNTc0trSS9WHxSAJgAWUhKwiKhOJi0YExjaeI5sJKcXEDT9Q2MzCysbfMKXAEYy1Eq1aqjxAQAzOYgNa2c5AE8GpUzEh3bORriEod8XIvQg0knItSZZhaWVmHXN82Md5I6D5ttvE6RkUihcJTTgQZy4Ag8GAQLRMF7bVq7FIgO6LZbtZ6NN7HFIjADsqH8V2mIF8EHqWOqiI+nFRDwxG0pPwKf0QpGQxM4SWh8hM2mkYioBBadiRHTBdPRq0ZW2xIF+xSCROB11qfK0Ap4wveeyiEvmaMemNlVPlLJS5RGIQAupMWOx9o5cKwqLpbOIfFwNBwojx+EJRBJbDAeLc5pZWAxQDA1rofSiQzQIHM1rYANa4VN601tZwAaUzXLFIEmMbjRa40OhsNsi1wchJCpI2HEEAAXj7VK2CCw5JxILAEJNu73OHhCMQS7bbcD7fHalBBijPd7Hbhna7g6HxOGuJGVNHY-HFnIjFxbLgAB66c9RagwIQAOg0cAgDeSU7tbHjBioAryy4CF68YhuuLputgiZhhGUbREenAnmeF7XreIAAIT3k+L5vlAH42jaLYaPINgHiAc60u2IplvGlhQGC8i2FAOhUGCDBYCMmBFJgpDWtgobaioFBFP4nHsSUM7MN+mhaHIljBvBUS0fRfaUMxrGIKA950FEoEbhBIB1g2oLVGE3BUEwAn0CAADEcxQP4UCkBoti2dQuDIMILmkCM-hFMIprWR5VDGMgLlBLgRG4CMLkaMgUCiHMLnuagGABXZUDoFQRReSMVDkCULl4iUGglHioXYNZVAjFAQRBJ5FUaHiuBBBo6CFagHnCNFFXhUEVAaP4LnCBo-lQM5FXUG59U2QCs2kGFwSLUN8UrS5NXrUEIASWRUmKfYywxvJ5aKVwdGjqpLrqfQ7GcdxvFmRZnboI+IyoJgz1vc9IkjNO2AulwabKKo1GcI4GjNgZXA6Egmk0Np0ROuBJaUEoGhWLo1ZMJwwpMIKMQNHg6qyY4ph0dIECtrC4gmFocwE7gDSI66JjCFQ4i9LCJiXhs2hKSwMQXkw2iLjDIDtGIosnn2GkokRCSpDJcnYIZJLqCEpkCLo94+qAl6S9YRlRJebWmVmoAq5wawm9gl7ZTLFtG9Fpt2+bBskmsTvq6WCncBFENzFD+6w7QnC-v+yMgIu4hoxAGMwljqSODQSh9FDGbUw4hSmPADOzMI7Pg-H1O0-TjNgczrPs6YnPc+qfPJwBTjCzrYvgreoDmGnLeyAo8a2QsJYa1ryei3r9tu5wxsR2bBkT1EVsR7b+v1iSl5O9gawu7PK+W+vs8eKLPeKI65niLmJCmRYMnQm6MsjgxUTAAA5NAT+ICYmGsI+0CYCYT9Nm-D+NAnxNhCIPbAcANQS3HgfGWR94yQkLF7b2x1ohXn9oHUWWk1x6QjlHGOccaxRDnDTOmuB+pwBMAuBm5lTC-jpiXXS4Ff60L5OLCQJhyQ02cFoemkZsBgjPP1aEAokBzHkOzbATctAixluwyWsIXCgHgZwAAEvWAU0IiImD4LgRQv8ACCVgGKmXkIQBOyj5DH1SPI0yld6xgm7lY+Mwg6gWEjKZKWh9nGcGsugfxEcjCXiUdvQ2IJPGKIAMqUVFvfaWIAAAUn9HyLgxpQgAvJkkwRQTAAH4TAjDQCYd+yS14mAALRAIfF-Y2ABKAAVEk4BX8PblOSVbBpj5-HoFIHiCOUsADy+1yQz2jsRTgWhhmHWVnPSOuA0ngNJMPIwo9YnmIfiAD6Jh6kmCadUx8xsTAAGoqlPjXrU6eayewbK2TsvZT4rbHNOS0kYFzkG2iAA)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your dataset "rawNumbers", values should only be provided for the "leave" nodes when using stratify transform.

```
    {
  "name": "rawNumbers",
  "values": [
    {"id": "completed stories", "parent": null},
    {"id": "testable", "parent": "completed stories"},
    {"id": "not testable", "parent": "completed stories", "amount": 1435},
    {"id": "sufficiently tested", "parent": "testable"},
    {"id": "insufficiently tested", "parent": "testable"},
    {"id": "integration tested", "parent": "sufficiently tested", "amount": 1758},
    {"id": "unit tested", "parent": "sufficiently tested", "amount": 36},
    {"id": "partial coverage", "parent": "insufficiently tested", "amount": 298},
    {"id": "no coverage", "parent": "insufficiently tested", "amount": 341}
  ]
},
```

[Open in Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4Ig7glgJgLgFiAXANgKwAYA0I4FMIDmcMSAzBtlAIYxVIDaoAdlQLa5IgBOVYAcgFdWAI1xcAziGwA3KgBsBuSYkYhonAMYB7VgAc5uGLigACcTC1cISqSF1UuuJiURMBcuQF9ModYhBG5lTCBrb2js6aOvqGxmYWVjbevlCcTFowJoG0IRzY4U4uINp6Bkam5pbWkthsWgKRiACMACzkyWqp-uICAGa9EBrWznIAnllK5WEOhZzZwaEdfmpMPf2DwzBjE+bG0xFF87kgS10rRgQ8MBBaTDtT+TONIGsDQ4Xb2Xu1rPWNTQB2VAADlOnAaEEyX1SjwOnFeGw+42htjqDRcpGQYP84Wu8hM2mkYioBDydieRQgqz6b02n0m3xAaMaACYAJygnydNJaAlaIk8Un7Wb+KkI94jZEMmFM37osgtJqeAC6HRY7DmjlwrCouls4nqXA0HH8PH4QlEElsMB4q16llYDFAMFGuhNLxtNAgvVGtgA1rhfaKZQVnABpQOcUMkDout1RhzXa63WwDXByM7MkjYcQQABeJtUuYILDknEgsAQHWLpc4eEIxBOqtVXPV7vSUBsOcNxs1uG1uuttvE9q4jpUztd7oGciMXFsuAAHrp5-5qDAhAA6DRwCAZiJNtVsd0GKhEmovHvum39nV67Ceu0Op0BKecGdzhfL1cgACE663Hc9ygA8VRVHMNHkGwJxANt4XzMk43dSwoCpeRbCgHQqCpBgsCaTAWUwUhlWwW0hRUCgWWBAi8JaFtmGPKI5Esa0338FC0LLSgsJwxBQHXOh-BvAd7xANMM04dRvG4KgmHI+gQAAYl6KBgSgUgNFsZTqFwZBhC00gmmBFlhBlRS9KoYxkC0tlcEg3Ami0jRkCgURei03TUAwMyVKgdAqBZAymiocgWi0gEWg0FoAWs7BFKoJooDZNl9LijQAVwNkNHQcLUD04RHLi2y2SoDRgS04QNFMqBNLi6gdNSpTkExFqbOQNl2tipTTJ6sykv6tkQHo2DGPY+whhdVj43YrhUNrbidV4+g8IIoiSJkuTC3QTcmlQTBtr27bqKaZtsB1Lg-WUVQkM4RwNGzMSuB0JB+JoQSAi1O8TkoJQNCsXRkyYThSSYYlAiyPA+WYxxTFQ6QIFzW5xBMLRegh3Ask+3UTGEKhxDiW4TEXcZtA4lhAgXJhtE7F6QEKMRaZnMs+JeSDQn8bRodTawJODE5pIEXR1xNUBF0ZnmzkXHLpKDUBxLOUZpewRdApZ+XOEXRyZdVuWJc4UYtc8I2uRu007Ie3onvHV7aE4U9z2+kBO3EP6IABm4gY5xwaCUeInoDZGHD+Ux4AxnphHx+6PeR1H0cx29sdx-HTEJ4m+TJn2LycamRbp5wGZZ8x-dz2QFHdZT+n57BBeF2mxbVvX-Clx3ZbExuQEVx2VfF9NJa17BRh1tve-1-u248WnS8UTVZPEaNHYsLRZzd2ma3Q-xgAAcmgTfEBMADWE3aBMBMTes13-eaC3LNPCrnB+QL3WJ5Zqf3UuSMjeNydpoCJcLat2mAk+wiUds7V27sUz+DbCjNGuBSpwBMB2DGslTCnjRrHYSd4T4oIJPTCQJhIQo2cLyUOjpsBUjnKVa4RIkC9HkPjbA2ctA0xZngxmtwXCgFfpwAAEumIk1xIImD4LgRQJ8ACCVh0LSXkIQT2XD5DTw5mw6SSd0xUhLoo90wgMgWEdNJJmk8tGcEUugMxC8-4915tyAxHCADKCFV5yPXiAAAFAfTcnYAYIIALx+JMCyEwAB+EwTQ0AmD3h4zWJgAC0l8NyHylgASgAFTuKvofA2MSPGK1SZuMx6BSAAkdkzAA8uNSErcXZQU4FoCpk1sDqzXLgbxd8a4+zrk4ksLiDomBSSYdJCTNxSxMAAaniVuTWSSW5dNrP4Xp-TBlbkVmMiZmSmjTM-mBIAA)

[image]

Comment: Wow... thank you. I do not see that tidbit of info within the documentation so I'm just wondering how you were able to figure that out? Also, can't upvote you because I do not have enough reputation.